# Type inference failure with F# gives an unclear error

Tags: f#, inotifypropertychanged, type-inference

I have the following ViewModelBase in F# which I'm trying to build to learn F# with WPF.

```
module MVVM

open System
open System.Collections.ObjectModel
open System.ComponentModel
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns
open System.Reactive.Linq


module Property =

    let ToName(query : Expr) = 
        match query with
        | PropertyGet(a, b, list) ->
            b.Name
        | _ -> ""

    let SetValue<'t>(obj, query : Expr<'t>, value : 't) =
        match query with
        | PropertyGet(a, b, list) ->
            b.SetValue(obj, value)
        | _ -> ()

    let GetValue<'o, 't>(obj : 'o , query : Expr<'t>) : option<'t> =
        match query with
        | PropertyGet(a, b, list) ->
            option.Some(b.GetValue(obj) :?> 't )
        | _ -> option.None

    let Observe<'t>(x: INotifyPropertyChanged) (p : Expr<'t>)  =
        let name = ToName(p)
        x.PropertyChanged.
            Where(fun (v:PropertyChangedEventArgs) -> v.PropertyName = name).
            Select(fun v -> GetValue(x, p).Value)

type ViewModelBase() =
    let propertyChanged = new Event<_, _>()

    interface INotifyPropertyChanged with
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member x.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish

    abstract member OnPropertyChanged: string -> unit

    default x.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName : string) =
        propertyChanged.Trigger(x, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))

    member x.SetValue<'t>(expr : Expr<'t>, v : 't) =
        Property.SetValue(x, expr, v)
        x.OnPropertyChanged(expr)

    member x.OnPropertyChanged<'t>(expr : Expr<'t>) =
        let propName = Property.ToName(expr)
        x.OnPropertyChanged(propName)
```

However I get an error from the compiler

```
Error   1   The type 'ViewModelBase' is used in an invalid way. 
A value prior to 'ViewModelBase' has an inferred type involving 
'ViewModelBase', which is an invalid forward reference.
```

However the compiler doesn't tell me what **value prior** is the offending part of the problem. As I'm pretty new to the type inference as used by F# I'm probably missing an obvious problem.

FYI the code is meant to be used like the below but at the moment this code is commented out and the error is only pertaining to the core code above

```
type TestModel() as this = 
    inherit MVVM.ViewModelBase()

    let mutable name  = "hello"

    let subscription = (Property.Observe this  <@ this.SelectedItem @>).
            Subscribe(fun v -> Console.WriteLine "Yo")

    member x.SelectedItem 
        with get() = name
        and set(v) = 
            x.SetValue(<@ x.SelectedItem @>, v)
```

Comment: I am trying to update the wiki to the tag [inpc] you have on your post what is it supposed to be?

Comment: INPC is the common acronym for INotifyPropertyChanged an interface for notifying property changes on objects mostly used in user interface design for MVC or MVVM patterns

Comment: Acronyms are vague.  We already have a tag for the real thing.

Comment: You're pulling in lots of advanced features for a noob. I'd advise using WPF directly programmatically in a typeful way and avoid all of the untyped stuff. Otherwise you run the risk of shoehorning a design pattern like MVVM that is meant for languages like C# into somewhere it doesn't naturally fit. In particular, your use of quotations is ringing alarm bells and I have no idea what problems any of the code you've posted actually solves.

Comment: @jon your comment is irrelevant to the question and has a condescending tone. Changing it as you have from an answer to a comment doesn't really add any value.

Comment: "...doesn't really add any value". The value is in pointing out that this is highly unidiomatic F# code that would not be seen in the wild.

Comment: And @jon will now show us his WPF framework using immutable persistent  state management. Til then I'll stick with a type safe INPC mechanism as used in most viewmodel base class examples for f#.

Comment: The best fit to the f# way from my investigations is Paul Betts reactiveui library based on reactive extensions. As events in f# are firstclass iobservable rather than the crap they are in c# reactiveui seems a good impedance match. However the typesafe INPC hooks in reactiveui are not compatible with f# as they use linq expression hacks which in f# are better handled by code quotations, thus my attempt at a bridging library or complete replacement for reactive ui

Comment: Btw I ripped my code from the wild http://fssnip.net/4Q with some minor changes

Comment: "type safe INPC mechanism". In what sense is this type safe? Your code is full of `obj` and `:?>`...

Comment: I passed you the link to the original source code. Please be polite enough to read it and understand before commenting on topics it seems you are not familiar with

Comment: Most people are aware that INPC is handled via string passing. The hack above uses code quotations to specify the property. Code quotations are not random strings. The compiler enforces type correctness.

Comment: However to do useful work the quotation must be processed. The casts you refer to are type safe in that they don't try to cast anything that violates the contract the code quotation tries to enforce. It might be possible to break. Let's call it "type safer" and be friends ;)

Comment: If you want to find similare type safe code, check the sample from fssnips from Phil Trelford. Don't have the link right now. As Jon points out your code seems unfocused. You don't need queries, quotations, to in the end, resorting to obj and dynamic typing.

Comment: Have a look at this. http://fssnip.net/2x

Comment: Actually your code is not bad,mbut it would need some cleanup

Comment: This whole discussion is a bit OT as i had only asked about the specific compiler error. Unfortunatly you are missing some context judging the code. 2nd jan I'll be back at work and I'll put the full lib on my blog and you can tear it apart there. But have a look at whenany function in paul betts reactive ui for an idea where this code will be used.

Comment: I created a github repo with the code if you still wish to provide some constructive feedback on the whole stack. https://github.com/bradphelan/FSharpWPFReactiveTest. The project runs. It's a pretty simple demo where you enter two numbers and a third number is updated being the sum of the first two.

Comment: The main program is https://gist.github.com/4433085 and as you can see is pretty simple.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Ok, I've been told from the high priest of F# that what I wrote here was wrong. He calls this style "name safe". I'll check out your sample ASAP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it.

```
let SetValue<'t>(obj, query : Expr<'t>, value : 't) =
    match query with
    | PropertyGet(a, b, list) ->
        b.SetValue(obj, value)
    | _ -> ()
```

was under constrained. Should be

```
let SetValue<'t>(obj : Object, query : Expr<'t>, value : 't) =
    match query with
    | PropertyGet(a, b, list) ->
        b.SetValue(obj, value)
    | _ -> ()
```

Comment: It always takes  two days before stack overflow will allow you to accept your own answer.